# Создание всевозможных операторов перегрузки C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

существует класс, в котором я хочу реализовать операторы перегрузок для базовых математических действий. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: функции операторов работают по одному и тому же принципу, но у них разная сигнатура. Как можно избавиться от данной проблемы и не писать:

```
class Test
{
    double a;
    public:
    Test& operator +=(const int b);
    Test& operator +=(const float b);
    Test& operator +=(const double b);
};
```

Есть ли способ сказать, что для всех сигнатур вида:

```
const T
```

Будет работать одинаковая реализация?

Comment: Как мне кажется это можно реализовать через `tempalte` метод с `std::enable_if` + `std::is_integral`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ - шаблоны.

```
class Test
{
    double a;
    public:
    template<typename T>
    Test& operator +=(const T b);
```

Если надо только для типов, которые можно суммировать с `double`, то можно воспользоваться концептом [`convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to).

Еще я не очень понимаю, зачем ставить `const` при передаче аргумента по значению. Вот если бы передавали `const T&` - тогда дело другое.

Comment: *зачем ставить const при передаче аргумента по значению* — в объявлении смысла может и нет, но в определении это позволяет избежать непреднамеренных изменений параметров, т.е. такой же смысл как и фундаментальные локальные переменные функции объявлять со спецификатором `const`

Comment: Да, большого смысла использовать const для передачи по значению нет - очепятался, а за ответ спасибо!!